# Django - Associating models with one another

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

As a part of a task, I created an "apartment listings" website. I managed to get that done, but now I need to make a "reservation system" for it.
The basic idea is that a logged in user can select an apartment from the listed apartments, pick a "start_date" and an "end_date" (if the apartment already isn't booked ) and book the apartment.
Im a total Django newbie, and need some pointers in order to start somewhere with this task.
I have an Apartment model which contains all of the Apartments info that I use to print everything out with the template.

I'm using the provided django user models to register / log-in.
I’m using Django 2.1.8

I have created this view  and model to make my reservations :

view:

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    context = {'apartment': apartment, }
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)

    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            # to go back to check that the info has changed
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/booking/')
    args = {}
    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'booking/index.html', args)
```

models:

```py
class Apartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    in_rent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Reservation(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, related_name='reservations',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Reservation"
```

my urls:

```py
app_name = "booking"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:apartment_id>/', views.apartment_view, name='apartment'),
    path('apartments/', views.ApartmentsView.as_view(), name='apartments'),
    # path('reservation/', views.CreateReservationView.as_view(), name='reservation'),
    path('search/', include('haystack.urls',)),

]
```

So with this I can create a reservation, but my problem is that the reservation doesnt automatically “connect” to the actual apartment listing, and I want it to be associated with it.
If I go into django admin I can see the reservation that was created, but I have to manually add the Apartment  to it.

How could I do this so it’s automatic ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to attach it during reservation like below.

```
if form.is_valid():
    reservation = form.save(commit=False)
    reservation.apartment = apartment
    reservetion.save()
    # to go back to check that the info has changed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ModelForm for Reservation you should be able to select a apartment and it would be saved automatically.